# Exports is not defined while using firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, svelte, svelte-3, sveltekit

I am getting this error while using firestore in typescript -

```
exports is not defined
ReferenceError: exports is not defined
    at eval (/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.node.cjs.js?v=470e9090:5:23)
    at instantiateModule (C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\game-store\node_modules\vite\dist\node\chunks\dep-713b45e1.js:66472:15)
```

I am using it with svelte kit.

I am following the docs on the firebase website and I think this error comes in `getFirestore` in `onMount`. this error happens sometimes and sometimes not.

Please help how to solve it!

Comment: Do you import getFirestore with `firebase/firestore`?

Comment: @Lyokolux Yes, like this `import {getFirestore} from "firebase/firestore"`

Comment: Please help! I added it to another page and the same error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there is a possible solution to your issue in a GitHub discussion I’ve found. They talk about incompatibility between firebase and svelte, but at the end someone commented this was an error caused by the imports. The [comment](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/1850#issuecomment-877544093) is:

> ...Looks like when you import "`@firebase/app`" instead of "`firebase/app`" it works. Seems like Vite is unable to resolve "firebase/app" to "`@firebase/app`" because the firebase team said it actually points to "`@firebase/app`"...

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer! I found somewhere that we can use dynamic imports in `onMount`, so I used that and that error did not happen